# Run Eclim on the remote server

Tags: eclipse, vim, docker, eclim

**Is it possible to run Eclim daemon on the remote server or share a volume to allow communication between the Vim container and the Eclipse + Eclim daemon?**

*I have a tiny Docker image with my Vim based development environment and I don't want to bloat it with Eclipse, but it will be nice to have Eclim features available.*

Comment: Consider asking on the [eclim-user](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/eclim-user) mailing list?

Comment: @FDinoff thx I'll try. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/eclim-user/JZ_NKiuI-gI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this isn't currently possible.

As the project owner, Eric Van Dewoestine, said in response to [your question in the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/eclim-user/JZ_NKiuI-gI).

> Eclim doesn't currently support having the daemon running on a 
>   different machine/vm than the client (vim).

Comment: Yes, he is the owner of the project and the lead contributor. https://github.com/ervandew/eclim